# Using meta instead of comments for discussion on suitability of a question

Tags: discussion, policy, comments

In [these](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5180/what-universities-in-the-united-states-or-in-europe-have-a-phd-focus-in-theoretic) [two](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5162/are-there-any-known-barriers-to-use-some-approach-for-solving-p-vs-np) questions, there's extensive discussion in comments (in one case in an answer) on the suitability of the question. To me, this seems like a discussion to be had here on meta, and so my question is:

> When such discussions start forming,
>   should we quickly shift the discussion
>   to meta, adding a link and strongly
>   encouraging commenters to move their
>   comments to the corresponding meta
>   thread ?

Comment: You are right Suresh. I guess we all got carried away today, or relaxed our guard, being Sunday and all.

Comment: Can the moderators somehow migrate comments to meta? Move or copy + delete?

Comment: we can't do migration of comments, only questions.

Comment: I agree. The first comments are OK, but if someone wants to argue against the first comments about closing then they should start a meta discussion and post a link to the meta discussion in the comments.